# Redshift Spectrum / The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I created a parquet file in S3 and an external table pointing to it in Redshift / Spectrum. Both my S3 bucket and Redshift cluster are in us-west-2. I specified the option region when creating the schema.

**Queries run smoothly in Athena.**

Yet when I run from Redshift client, I get this error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
>
> ### Details:
>
> error:  S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
>    code:      15001
>    context:   Task failed due to an internal error. 
>   HTTP response error code: 301 Message: PermanentRedirect The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. >Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
>   x-amz-request-id: XXXX
>    query:     XXXXX
>    location:  dory_util.cpp:689
>    process:   query0_40 [pid=XXX]
>    -----------------------------------------------;

Comment: Can you show the command you used in Redshift Spectrum? That error message is always in relation to mismatched regions. Have you managed to get Spectrum working in any other situation?

Comment: Thanks as mentioned in the question, we made sure it was in the same region. However, AWS has acknowledged a defect and released a patch overnight - it is now corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has acknowledged the issue and released a patch overnight.

Comment: any reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your Redshift cluster is running with at least version 1.0.14016 in us-east-2 or us-west-2 and 1.0.1407 in us-east-1. To apply the patch to Redshift immediately, move the maintenance window of your cluster closer to the current time and day to pick it up at your convenience.